I'm animating a hand picking up a plate. Why do the fingers remain in the most recent pose even when I try to play the animation from the beginning?
I'm trying to animate an alien hand picking up a plate using keyframes. This is my first animation, by the way.
I'm able to pose the hand just fine. But when I try to play the animation, the fingers always remain in the last position even though I had initially posed them differently. The location and rotation of the hand always show up correctly. It's just the fingers that seem to be the issue.

Here you can see the pose of the hand on frame 7. The hand is mostly open and the fingers are barely bent.

Here on frame 8 you can see that I've bent the fingers in, closer to the plate.

Here you can see at the beginning of the animation that the hand is back at the location and rotation as I established for frame 1. But for some reason, the fingers are stuck at the pose they were in at the final frame.
I've tried creating more distance from one keyframe to the next. I also tried selecting 'location, rotation, and scale' for every keyframe even if all I changed was the location or location and rotation, and tried using Auto-IK.
What did I do wrong?

Hello, at frame 1, have you created some keyframes for the fingers you are talking about?

You forgot to set the key when you move it (alternatively use Auto key, with it on any movement automatically creates a key)

@moonboots Yes, I had a keyframe for how the hand looked at the beginning.

@BuzzKirill Do I need to set a keyframe each time I move a finger? I thought I could move all the fingers to how I wanted them to look and then set a keyframe.

please share the file (only the hand armature) so that we can test it

I tried entering a keyframe every time I changed one finger rather than changing all the fingers and then trying to create a keyframe and now everything is working as it should. Thanks for all the responses!
